# How to add SearchController.searchBar under navigationBar (UITableView) swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I try to add SearchController.searchBar under navigation bar.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false //
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        let SearchFrame = CGRectMake(0,(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!, (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.width)!,searchController.searchBar.frame.height)
        searchController.searchBar.frame = SearchFrame
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
}
```

This code add a searchBar under navigationBar, but searchBar can't detect user interaction! I can't click on search text input field!! What did I do wrong?

Comment: Let's try some debugging.
`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = true` -> if your `UISearchBar` disappears, it means you didn't change your navigation bar's height.

Comment: @noir_eagle,Yes, my UISearchBar disappear in this case! what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved!

First we need to create a XIB file with class and add two navigationBar to them!
Then need to add a IBOutlets!
[image: Two navigation bar in xib!]

Then write the code:

```
var TitleNavigationBar = UINavigationBar() //This need to add Title and Subtitle to NavigationBarTitleView

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let NavBarWithSearch = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("NavBarWithSearchBar", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! NavBarWithSearchBar
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake((self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.origin.x)!, 0.0, (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.width)!, (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)! +          self.searchController.searchBar.frame.height)
        NavBarWithSearch.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0, (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.width)!, (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!)
        NavBarWithSearch.NavigationBarForSearchBar.topItem?.titleView = searchController.searchBar
        TitleNavigationBar = NavBarWithSearch.CustomNavigationBar //=======This need to add Title and Subtitle to NavigationBarTitleView`
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(NavBarWithSearch)
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake((self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)! + UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height, 0, (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height)!, 0)
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
}
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        //This need to add Title and Subtitle to NavigationBarTitleView
        let titleView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("NavTitleView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! NavTitleView
        titleView.TitleLabel.text = "Title"
        titleView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        titleView.SubtitleLabel.text = "SubTitle"
        let TitleViewFrame = CGRectMake((UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/2) - 80, 0, 160, 44)
        titleView.frame = TitleViewFrame
        TitleNavigationBar.topItem?.titleView = titleView
        //========This need to add Title and Subtitle to NavigationBarTitleView
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake((self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.origin.x)!, 20, (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.width)!, (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)! + self.searchController.searchBar.frame.height)

}
```

XIB file with Class for NavBarTitleView with subtitle should be look like
like this:
[image: Title and SubTitle]

Finally i get beautiful Navigation Bar with search bar!

[image: Navbar with search bar text input]

P.S. searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true // This doesn't work because Custom navigation bar added to main navigation bar as subview!

Comment: Ignoring the non camel case conventions, I can't express how bad this is to do.

Comment: @TheCodingArt, I understand... but i can't  find any other solution!

Comment: I just did it today.... added a view underneath the navbar, blended the 2 together and had a child VC with a table VC in it underneath.... again as a note to the above, you should never have a variable and/or method/function name start with caps... ever.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me

```
    var SearchFrame : CGRect?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false //
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        SearchFrame = CGRectMake(0,(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!, (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.width)!,searchController.searchBar.frame.height)
        searchController.searchBar.frame = SearchFrame!
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)


    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        var navbarFrame = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame
        navbarFrame.size = CGSize(width: navbarFrame.width, height: navbarFrame.height + SearchFrame!.height)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = navbarFrame
    }
```

Comment: In this case leftBarButton TitleView and rightBar button is under search bar! How to fix it?

Comment: Well, you would need to add them as subviews with fixed frames then, instead of setting properties for navigationItem.